# How Do I Implement CGI In My Custom Node.js Server?

Tags: php, node.js, server, cgi

I'm planning on extending my custom node.js server to implement CGI connections to script executors such as PHP. In order to set PHP's $_GET, $_POST and $_SERVER variables, so that I can run PHP scripts, I need to know something about how CGI achieves this.

Having taken a look at RFC3875, I understand that I need to set certain defined variables, by composing a document containing those variables and their values, for example, REQUEST_METHOD="GET" or REQUEST_METHOD="POST" as appropriate.

The multi part question I have to ask is this.

[1] How is the document thus created passed to the PHP executable, so that it can populate its variables?

[2] What entries in the document do I use to populate $_GET and $_POST, if any?

[3] If populating $_GET and $_POST is achieved by a different mechanism, what mechanism is used, and how would I implement this?

Please bear in mind the following:

[1] I'm completely new to the business of **implementing** CGI as opposed to merely using it, so I'd welcome step by step breakdowns as appropriate;

[2] I'm not looking for an off the shelf solution, I'm looking for information allowing me to *write my own code* to perform this task, so that I can learn properly how CGI operates.

I have written a node.js server that handles GET and POST successfully for node.js server side scripts, and all I need now is the above information to allow me to extend this functionality to CGI scripts using PHP (and possibly Perl as well if I have the time to investigate handling Perl scripts).

All offers of relevant information welcome in advance.

Answer (score 0):

RFC3875 is a bit obtuse in defining what the "documents" and "meta-variables" actually mean.

What it means in practice is:

- A CGI script or executor (like PHP) is launched as an executable. In node.js terms, this probably means using `child_process.spawn()`. The CGI script does not need to be passed any command-line arguments.
- CGI's "request meta-variables" are passed to the executable as environment variables.
- If the script is being called for a request with a body (like POST or PUT), the body of the request is passed in on standard input. This is the "request message-body".
- The script will print a result on standard output which resembles an HTTP response. This is the "CGI response". The result can generally be parsed as if it were an HTTP response, but certain headers (particularly `Status` and `Location`) will need some special handling.

Comment: So what you're saying is, that [1] I need to pass entities such as the query string, other command line args, and the other CGI standard variables using a setenv-type call (or by creating an env variable to be passed to the spawn() options), [2] launch the spawn call with that, and [3] if I'm also sending a POST body, write that to the child STDIN after spawning. Am I correct?